# CTE recursion () SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [HR].[Employees]
(
    [empid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [firstname] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [titleofcourtesy] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [birthdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [hiredate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [city] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [region] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [postalcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [country] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [nvarchar](24) NOT NULL,
    [mgrid] [int] NULL
)
```

This is my query

```
WITH EmployeeCTE AS
(
    --- le patron 
    SELECT
        [firstname] + space(2) + [lastname] AS [Full Name],
        [title], [mgrid]
    FROM
        [HR].[Employees]
    WHERE
        mgrid IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        S.[firstname] + space (2) + s.[lastname] AS [fullname],
        S.[title], S.[mgrid]
    FROM
        [HR].[Employees] S 
    INNER JOIN 
        [HR].[Employees] M ON M.empid = s.mgrid
 )
 SELECT * 
 FROM
     (SELECT C.[Full Name], T.[title]  
      FROM [HR].[Employees] T 
      INNER JOIN EmployeeCTE c ON c.mgrid = T.empid) AS Manager 
 FROM
     EmployeeCTE
```

I want to use CTE recursion to know the hierarchy in this table but I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near from

Can you help me please ?

Comment: The error is because you have two `FROM` clauses in your final query. A recursive CTE must reference itself.

Comment: Chandge `inner join [HR].[Employees] M` to `inner join EmployeeCTE M`, and remove the last line `from EmployeeCTE`